# Sharepoint Foundation 2013, multiple config databases

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have reinstalled Sharepoint server 2013 Foundation on same machine i.e Windows Server 2008 R2 after unistalling previous installation. There was problem occurred in Domain controller.

Now the problem I see here is multiple Sharepoint_config databases(around 6-7) created ex Sharepoint_config_fe37218h982, Sharepoint_config_ferrasdf224 etc. Also it took diffrent MSSQLSERVER session eg: ServerName/Sharepoint

Everything else is working fine, I want to know why it created multiple? earlier it was Single only.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running product configuration wizard you might have chosen the

> Create a new server farm

instead of

> Connect to an existing server farm

. This might be the cause to the multiple Database creation.

[image]

If you are selecting create a new server farm then all your old site collection web application details will be gone for now. and it will create new configuration data base and with new fresh SharePoint instance.

So if you want old Web Applications and SharePoint sites and all old settings then you have to go with connect to an existing farm option there you can have all your old sites.

Note :- until you delete the data base from site you don't have to worry because in future you connect to your existing farm by selecting server and configuration db.

Comment: Will it create problem in future?

Comment: Not sure but if all old site working fine then i think you don't have to worry i guess, but better make sure which configuration database is correct one.

Comment: @Raghvendra, It took new MSSQLServer sessions eg: ServerName\Sharepoint\Sharepoint_Config_xxxxxx old sites are not working. I am able to create New sites, WFs etc and they are working fine.

Comment: OK, i have modified and added few point in last in my post according to your scenario